# Performance degrades when php getmxrr() is called from inside shell for loop

Tags: php, bash, performance-testing

I noticed big performance difference when tried to fetch MX of gmail 100000 times using php and shell script.

PHP script is taking around 1.5 min.

```
<?php
$time = time();
for($i=1;$i<=100000;$i++)
{
    getmxrr('gmail.com', $hosts, $mxweights);
    unset($hosts, $mxweights);
}
$runtime = time() - $time;
echo "Time Taken : $runtime Sec.";
?>
```

But same thing done inside shell for loop is almost 10 times slower

```
time for i in {1..100000}; do (php -r 'getmxrr("gmail.com", $mxhosts, $mxweight);');done
```

I am curious to know, what are the reasons, shell script is taking more time to complete exactly the same thing which php script can do very fast.

Comment: Are you aware you are launching 10.000 PHP **processes** using your second option, in addition to executing the php function `getmxrr()` also 10.000 times?

Comment: Ys @Tobias, that was in my mind, but I had doubt about the difference. Would it be so expensive for shell to do it with separate process? And ys I know, its querying for MX 1lac times when I m doing getmxrr() inside loop.